# How to subtract 1 day (calculate day before) in XSLT 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Could someone please help calculate one day ago from a given date of type `xsd:dateTime` using XSLT 2.0?

**Sample Input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects>
<LastRunTime__c>
<Last_Run_Time__c>2015-01-29T19:55:15.846Z</Last_Run_Time__c>
</LastRunTime__c>
</objects>
```

**Sample Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects>
<LastRunTime__c>
<Last_Run_Time__c>2015-01-28T19:55:15.846Z</Last_Run_Time__c>
</LastRunTime__c>
</objects>
```

**I was trying a few things but was not able to get what I want:**

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="vToday" select="/*:objects/*:LastRunTime__c/*:Last_Run_Time__c"/>
Today is: <xsl:sequence select="$vToday"/>
1 day ago it was: <xsl:sequence select="$vToday -1*xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with the date format. Have you tried `<Last_Run_Time__c>2015-01-28</Last_Run_Time__c>` or `<Last_Run_Time__c>2015-01-28-19:55</Last_Run_Time__c>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Given your input XML, this XSLT transformation:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="vToday" select="/objects/LastRunTime__c/Last_Run_Time__c" 
                  as="xsd:dateTime"/>
    Today is: <xsl:value-of select="$vToday"/>
    1 day ago it was: <xsl:value-of select="$vToday - xsd:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Will produce the desired output:**

```
    Today is: 2015-01-29T19:55:15.846Z
    1 day ago it was: 2015-01-28T19:55:15.846Z
```

Comment: Than you! that helped.